# Call JavaScript from Silverlight hosted in IFrame

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, iframe

I am developing a Silverlight application which is going to be hosted inside another's application IFrame:

```
<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testMethod() {
        alert(1);
    }       
</script>
<iframe src="URL of the silverlight application" width="750" height="500"/>
```

This is just a dummy app for testing purposes (I am using the default MVC 4 template - this is actuly the Contacts.cshtml file)

An this is the part where I call the JavaScript function.

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("testMethod");
```

Any suggestions what to do/what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the javascript console? Did you enable the HTMLBridge: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645023(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Yes I did (now) and still nothing... I am pretty new to web developement so can't be that precise :/ Both are hosted on localhost atm (localhost/MvcApplication1 and localhost/SilvelrightApp)

Comment: So you did set the `enableHtmlAccess` parameter?

Comment: Just saw that the original application had also a `testMethod` which was empty so that's why it wasn't called in the first place... Now I am getting an exception that the testMethod is not defined...

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:-

```
ScriptObject parent = HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("parent") as ScriptObject;
if (parent != null)
{
     parent.Invoke("testMethod");
}
```

Comment: First time I tested it I was getting an error but now it seems to work... maybe I misspelled something... sorry about that... and thanks for your solution :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Is that a cross browser solution by any chance?

Comment: @Dmitry: Yes this approach will work in any browser supported by Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me in this case

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("if(typeof window.parent.testMethod== 'function'){window.parent.testMethod()};");
```

I know that `.Eval` should be avoided but it looks like it's the only way for me :/

Comment: It would be appropriate to resolve why you need to resort to .Eval?  On the basis of the above the my answer ought to work too.  Hence something is still to be understood.